# Rviz not subscribing to visualization_marker?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add points to rviz following the tutorial "Markers: Points and Lines". Even when I followed the code and instructions exactly like in the tutorial, I could not see the markers displayed in rviz. $rostopic echo visualization_marker showed that the topic was published well and continuously. When I tried $rostopic info visualization_marker, I realized that there was no subscriber to the topic. How come rviz was not subscribing to the topic? Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212216/rviz-not-subscribing-to-visualization_marker?/) by [Audi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22946/audi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-26**:
Is RViz properly configured? Does it has any warning or error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So sorry, I skipped the first tutorial. I need to add a "markers" display first from the GUI to make rviz subscribe to the vizualisation_marker topic. Now it is working fine and displaying the markers.

---

Originally posted by [Audi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22946/audi/) with karma: 1 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0